# GSON parses null value as empty field like {"field": , "otherField": "value"}

Tags: java, json, null, gson

My Gson conversion are saving values "null" like empty field value, this broke Json result. Someone can help me?

**Expected:**

```
{"field": null, "otherField": "value"}
```

**result:**

```
{"field": , "otherField": "value"}
```

Comment: What is the object you're serializing? What does the Gson/GsonBuilder object look like? Post some code.

Comment: Try [`GsonBuilder.serializeNulls`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeNulls()).